# ctrl+shift+m shortcut for display math not functioning in lyx on windows and how to make it work?

Tags: lyx, shortcut

I believe ctrl+shift+m should be a default shortcut for creating display maths in lyx as is mentioned on https://wiki.lyx.org/Tips/FrequentlyUsedShortcuts and on my linux machine it does do that. However, on my windows machine nothing happens when I press those keys. So, I'm wondering whether this is expected behaviour on windows and furthermore how I could activate this shortcut?

Edit: I checked the preferences -> shortcuts and yes I have the standard cua shortcuts in which there is ctrl+shift+m for creating the display math and yet, nothing happens

Comment: Strange, I haven't heard of this issue. The point of this comment is just to confirm that I have the same expectation as you did that it should also work on Windows. A shot in the dark, but the only thing I can think of is that the shortcut is intercepted at a higher level. Maybe some program (AutoHotKey?) you use on Windows has already registered that shortcut.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that the hotkey was being intercepted by another program, in this case, AMD Radeon Software. Thanks for scottkosty for pointing this out in his comment, I had suspected something similar at first, however as I don't use any program like autohotkey so I didn't know what could be intercepting it, so yea if someone else is experiencing a similar issue, I reccomend checking all other programs with any system-wide shortcuts, fairly obvious in hindsight.

Comment: Bingo. Just switched to an AMD graphics card and was having this issue, so I suspected it was something involved with that. If you open the AMD "adrenaline" software, click on settings (the gear-shaped icon on the top right), then go to hotkeys, and scroll down to the bottom you can see ctrl+shift+m is the default "toggle microphone" hotkey. Since I don't need this functionality, I just deleted the hotkey to fix the problem.